# Definition of magnetic field $H$ in ferromagnetism

Tags: magnetic-fields

I am thinking how you can define explicitly the [magnetic field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) $H$ in a ferromagnetic material.
I think the Maxwell's equation should apply. 
However, I am not completely sure which form. 
[Here](http://www.science.unitn.it/~visintin/ARMA2005.pdf) are some manipulations but not sure about validity. 
[Here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ivan_Cimrak/publication/223275477_Numerical_study_of_nonlinear_ferromagnetic_materials/links/0912f50ae3eb319951000000.pdf) about numerical study.

How can you define $H$ in ferromagnetic material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$, $H$ and $M$ are related by $H=B-4\pi M$ (in Gaussian units).
Beyond that, what each is depends on the geometry, and on the type of ferromagnet.
Is it a permanent magnet or is it a 'soft' ferromagnet that does not hold its magnetization without current?
Only inside a torus does H depend only on the current.
Surface effects are very important, but it is always true that $H=B-4\pi M$ (which is the definition of $H$).

Comment: Answers generally shouldn't ask OP for more information. Put those questions as comments.